# Kio estas la diferenco inter "volonte" kaj "libervole"?

Tags: word-difference

Mi konas la divenon de la vortoj: *liber* + *vol* + *e* kaj *vol* + *ont* + *e*. Kvankam mi vidas malsaman signifon en ili, ŝajnas al mi kvazaŭ ili estas uzataj same. Kelkfoje kiam, laŭ mi, *libervole* pli taŭgus oni uzas tamen *volonte*. Kiel la vortoj malsamas?

- Vi ne devas ĉiam fari kion Marko volas.

  - Ĉu vi celas la artikolon? Tiun mi skribis (…)
- Kiom ŝi pagas vin?

  - Neniom, mi laboras (…)
- Ĉu vi povus helpi min baki la torton?

  - (…)!

Comment: Fakte, "*volont/*" estas propra radiko: http://vortaro.net/#volonte Tio ja estas iom stranga afero kiu longe konfuzis min!

Comment: @kristan Ho! Subite cxio klarigxas! Mi ne komprenis kial oni uzis la estontecan participon. Do bone, dankon. Tio certe gravas al la fadeno.

Answer (score 6):

"Volonte" estas multe pli entuziasma. Oni povas libervole fari aferojn kiuj ne estas agrablaj, sed se oni faras ion "volonte" tio signifas ke one vere volas fari ĝin (aŭ provas ŝajnigi tion). Cetere, nek "volonte" nek "libervole" signifas "senpage."

(Elpensitaj ekzemploj)

- Neniu devigis al mi tatui la vorton "stultulo" sur mia frunto. Mi faris libervole.
- Ŝi ne pagas min. Mi estas volontulo kaj laboras senpage.
- Volonte mi bakos kukon ... se mi povos ankaŭ manĝi ĝin.

Por "senpage" ankaŭ eblas uzi "volont**ul**e. (Ekzemploj el la Tekstaro.)

- por volontule kolekti botelojn
- Ili volontule portis provizojn kaj faris aliajn taskojn
- [Ni] volontule laboris por komenci konstrui labirinton por meditado apud Krimulda preĝejo

kaj

- Per mono li povis aĉeti la volontan silentadon de la servistoj

(Sed ne la volontulan silenton.)